# Why the btn and the h1 still at the same line?

Tags: html, css, display

I want that the button of play again and the `h1` will be in different lines. How can I do it?

```html
<div class="winner">
  <h1 class="won">You Won!</h1>
  <button class="again">Play Again!</button>
</div>
```

```css
.winner {
  background-color: #9792e3;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
.won {
  color: #e85f5c;
  font-family: "Anton", sans-serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
.again {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Here is the image:
[image]

Comment: You have problem with `.winner` css, because you making `button` into `<div class="winner">` and in `.winner` have a `display: flex;` code

Comment: then how can I fix it, I set again class to block, sry if I ask stupid questions I'm just new to this stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.winner {
  background-color: #9792e3;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
.won {
  color: #e85f5c;
  font-family: "Anton", sans-serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
.again-div {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="winner">
<h1 class="won">You Won!</h1>
<button class="again">Play Again!</button>
</div>
```

Add `flex-direction: column;`

Answer (score 0):

You are using Flex which has the default direction vale as a row due to which it is showing in the same line, either you can remove the display flex property or change its direction to the column. here my modified code where I removed the flex property.

**code**

```
            <div class="winner">
            <h1 class="won">You Won!</h1>
            <button class="again">Play Again!</button>
            </div>  

            .winner {
                background-color: #9792e3;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                transform: translateY(-100%);
            }
            .won {
                color: #e85f5c;
                font-family: "Anton", sans-serif;
                font-size: 3rem;
            }
            .again {
                display: block;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
```